# Symbol undefined error for dropzone in IE11

Tags: dropzone.js

The latest dropzone.js version does not seem to work in IE11. How to test?

1) Open up https://www.dropzonejs.com/examples/simple.html in IE11
2) dropzone not clickable and files cannot be dragged and dropped

The error via F12 console is:

> 'Symbol' is undefined
>   File: dropzone.js, Line: 3196, Column: 11

```
if (_didIteratorError32) {
  throw _iteratorError32;
}
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: I looked a bit further to figure out what the 'Symbol' is undefined meant and if I look at page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/description, I see that Internet Explorer does NOT support the standard built in object "Symbol". If this is the cause, it would mean that the latest dropzone.js is incompatible with Internet Explorer. Can somebody confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding following script tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.8.7/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Dropzone.js had arrow functions and lot of other things which are not supported in IE11. Therefore, it converted from es6 to es5 using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

After researching a bit found that it needed polyfill support and hence script.

Comment: Thanks @poojakapuriya! That solves part of the problem. After addition of the polyfill script, you can click on the dropzone, select a file and then upload it. However it is still not possible in IE11 to drag and drop a file on the dropzone. Do you have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with 'Symbol' is undefined in IE11 with Dropzone.js version 5.7.0 release that was (at the time of writing) still referenced from Dropzone.js website.

Issue was actually solved just by downloading latest release from GitHub which (at the time of writing) was Release v5.9.2.

So no need for explicit babel-polyfill anymore.

https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/releases

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem when I downloaded the script directly from the website https://www.dropzonejs.com/js/dropzone.js?v=1583771423.

Comment: Please don't post links without context